# The "Sitecore Client Users" role and concurrent user limit?

Tags: sitecore-client, role-management, user-management

Let's say your license limits you to `10 concurrent CMS users` at once. If someone's user account is in the `Sitecore Client Users` role, and they log in with that account, do they count as a concurrent CMS user who occupies one of those 10 spots?

From the [Sitecore documentation](https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/90/platform-administration-and-architecture/en/the-security-roles.html):

**Sitecore Client Users**

> Gives the user minimal access to Sitecore. With this role, the user can log in to the Sitecore Desktop, but will not have access to any applications.
>
> All of the other Sitecore client roles are members of the Sitecore Client Users role, which means that users in any Sitecore client role are automatically members of the Sitecore Client Users role.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.

Every user that logs into the Sitecore Client (any Sitecore Client, be it Content Editor, Experience Editor etc) will count as 1 towards your concurrent user license limitation.

It matters not what role(s) they're in.